# Bottom Overflow in Container with fixed and flexible elements

Tags: flutter, dart, scroll, height, overflow

I'm trying to create some sort of bottom sheet in Flutter, which can be dragged to full-screen or set in minimized state.

For this I use a `Positioned` and a `Container`. In this bottom sheet I want a header which should not be scrollable and a scrollable body.
I created this dartpad to represent the situation: https://dartpad.dev/b6409e10de32b280b8938aa75364fa7b

In the stage 3 everything works fine and the body is scrollable, but in Stage 1 I experience a bottom overflow error and I don't know how to fix this.

I tried to use `Expanded` and `Flexible` with several options, I also tried using the `Wrap` widget for preventing the body to overflow.

Can you help me with this problem?

The build function from the dartpad looks like this:

```dart
    Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
          return Stack(
            children: [
              Column(children: [
                Row(children: [
                  RaisedButton(
                    child: Text("Stage 1"),
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        height = 40;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                  RaisedButton(
                    child: Text("Stage 2"),
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        height = 80;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                  RaisedButton(
                    child: Text("Stage 3"),
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        height = 150;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ])
              ]),
              Positioned(
                bottom: 0,
                width: constraints.maxWidth,
                height: height,
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Column(children: [
                        Text("Fixed"),
                        Text("Fixed"),
                        Text("Fixed"),
                      ]),
                      Flexible(
                          child: SingleChildScrollView(
                              child: Column(children: [
                        Container(
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            width: constraints.maxWidth,
                            height: 30),
                        Container(
                            color: Colors.red,
                            width: constraints.maxWidth,
                            height: 30),
                        Container(
                            color: Colors.green,
                            width: constraints.maxWidth,
                            height: 30),
                        Container(
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            width: constraints.maxWidth,
                            height: 30),
                      ])))
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
```

This is the app in Stage 2 (everything works fine):
[image: Stage 2]

When I shrink the container height, I get this error:
[image: Stage 1]

Comment: Should the bottom slider be displayed as an overlay?

Comment: Yes, it is used within a `Positioned` and a `Stack` and therefore an overlay.

Comment: Can you try [this](https://pub.dev/packages/draggable_bottom_sheet) plugin?